# need to find need to find yesterday's date in a txt file and add to a bat file

Tags: requirements.txt

I need to search a txt file for a specific line and count it - I also need to find yesterday's date  - i have created the first part see below but I cannot workout the second part.
the line is 2017-07-04 15:19:00 Resultat de la copie: 0 (Succes:0 Error:1)

---

```
    @ECHO OFF

    FIND /c "Resultat de la copie: 0 (Succes:0 Error:1)" C:\dashboard.txt

    PAUSE

    cls

   set file=c:\newfile.txt
   set /a cnt=0
   for /f %%a in ('type "%files%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
   echo %this file% has %cnt% lines

   EXIT

   PAUSE
```